# Using sshpass with bash works from command line, not from java exec

Tags: java, bash, ssh, exec, runtime.exec

I have a bash script, that uses sshpass and ssh to autologin to different machine and trigger command. The bash script works well, when triggered from the command line, but when it is called from java application, it fails to proceed.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX './SleepDisplay && exit'
```

The bash script does a lot of other things and I have no way to implement the ssh login directly in java. I don't seem to be able to figure out, why it fail. Everything but the ssh runs well.

Comment: You are not going to get any help by saying `it's not working`. What's not working? Where is the code? How are you executing the command?

Comment: consider editing your question to include the lines in context of your java, AND (more importantly) any error messages you can capture. Does the call in java return a fail status? Can you embed shell debugging into above command, i.e. `set -vx; sshpass ...`. Does your JAVA have the same PATH as the terminal that you run your shell code it. Consider adding `echo $PATH; set -vx; sshpass ...` to validate PATH is correct. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing commands via `Runtime.exec()`, the *first* element is the *executable*, then all other parameters are passed in separately in the rest of the array.

But you are (probably) passing the *whole linux* command in as the executable, which doesn't work.

Try this:

```
String[] cmdarray = {"sshpass", "-p", "'password'", "ssh", "user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "'./SleepDisplay && exit'"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
```

Comment: the problem is that exec() calls just the bash script
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec('bashscriptname')`
the sshpass is inside the script with a lot of other commands, that work ok.

Answer (score 1):

Open a shell first and execute the command. Try something like the following:

```
 String COMMAND = "sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX './SleepDisplay && exit'";
 String[] SHELL_COMMAND = { "/bin/sh", "-c", COMMAND };
 ...
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process process = runtime.exec(SHELL_COMMAND);
```

Hope I could give you a helpful hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `ganymed-ssh2` java library, it's let you able to perform and execute shell scripts and so on using java...
Below is showed an example using this library:

```
{
    String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    String username = "joe";
    String password = "joespass";

    try
    {
        /* Create a connection instance */

        Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);

        /* Now connect */

        conn.connect();

        /* Authenticate.
         * If you get an IOException saying something like
         * "Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage."
         * then please check the FAQ.
         */

        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

        if (isAuthenticated == false)
            throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

        /* Create a session */

        Session sess = conn.openSession();

                    // here execute which command separate for ";" 
        sess.execCommand("uname -a && date && uptime && who");

        System.out.println("Here is some information about the remote host:");

        /* 
         * This basic example does not handle stderr, which is sometimes dangerous
         * (please read the FAQ).
         */

        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while (true)
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        /* Show exit status, if available (otherwise "null") */

        System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitStatus());

        /* Close this session */

        sess.close();

        /* Close the connection */

        conn.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
```